# EasyPHP 16.1.1 unable to start MySQL

Tags: mysql, easyphp

Firstly, after first run after installation, everything works fine; but now, after hour and restart later, when I start **EasyPHP Dashboard**, *MySQL is not running*. When I try to start it, loading circle appears, then page is refreshed and *MySQL* is still not started - without any message. I erased Error log and directly after try to run, it writes following:

```
2016-05-21T08:39:32.432081Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2016-05-21T08:39:32.432081Z 0 [Warning] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
2016-05-21T08:39:32.432081Z 0 [Warning] 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER' sql mode was not set.
2016-05-21T08:39:32.432081Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --secure-file-priv: Current value does not restrict location of generated files. Consider setting it to a valid, non-empty path.
2016-05-21T08:39:32.432081Z 0 [Note] ..\eds-binaries\dbserver\mysql5711x86x160521094439\bin\eds-dbserver.exe (mysqld 5.7.11) starting as process 1732 ...
```

Do you have any idea, what happens and how to solve it?

EDIT:After a few reinstalls is situation still same. Directly after installation everything works, but after easyphp is closed, MySQL never starts again. Errorlog always says, that mysql is starting process xxxx, but that process never starts.

Comment: How did you verify that the process is not running? By not being able to login to your database? The more usual suspect then would be a wrong user/password or wrong connection settings. Please check your process list.

Comment: By look at Task Manager... But if I tried EasyPHP 14.11, there is same problem but error msg appears there. Its really interesting, that first run is ok, i am not doing anything with settings or something else at that first run.

Comment: I'm still not convinced it is not running, can you check again please: run `cmd` as adminstrator(!!) (right click, "run as administrator"), then enter `tasklist /FI "PID eq 1732"` (or whatever the id is now). That it works the first time might be because you ran it as an admin during install. Maybe you didn't install it correctly and it has not enough rights or required not login. Can you start it manually? What happens? Start it as admin? What happens? What happens if you start it manually with `--skip-grant-table`? And please add any "but error msg appears there"-error messages...

Comment: Tasklist cmd shows, that PID doesn't exists (current, of course). If I tried to start dbserver manually (mysql.exe ?) it writes, ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061), or if I try to run eds-dbserver via cmd, it echoes nothing. All as user/admin. And skip geant table: C:\WINDOWS\system32>"C:\Programs\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-binaries\dbserver\mysql5711x86x160523223621\bin\mysql.exe" --skip-grant-table
mysql: [ERROR] unknown option '--skip-grant-table'

Comment: And error in 14.11 is 
2016-05-26 21:57:18 288 [ERROR] InnoDB: File C:\Programs\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\binaries\mysql\data\ib_logfile0: 'aio read' returned OS error 187. Cannot continue operation
I heard about mysql optiom innodb_flush_method=normal, to solve this error, but it doesn't solve anything.

Comment: do you have any previously installed mysql?

Comment: no, all after freshly installed and updated Windows 10 Home 64bit. Firstly 16.1.1 and then 14.11 after 16.1.1 stop working

Comment: Would you mind running: `"C:\Programs\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-binaries\dbserver\my‌​sql5711x86x160523223621\bin\mysql.exe`? Your previous attempt at starting the server from the command line failed because of an unknown option. This command does not include that option! Can you report back with the output?

Comment: Have you checked the services? On my computer another MySQL service was blocking the recent one from version 16.1.1

Comment: @SilentCry have you found a solution to this? I'm having the exact same problem!

Answer (score 2):

Install `MySQL Server` separately don't install the MySQL that comes with `EasyPHP`. And the `MySQL` service starts at the start of Operating System, you don't need to start the service in `EasyPHP`.

Please note that if you want to use this installation with `phpMyAdmin`, you should adjust configuration of `phpMyAdmin` (likely your MySQL password) or alternatively you can use Database GUI tools like `MySQL Workbench`.

Hope this helps you. [I am using `XAMPP` with the same procedure. It works for me]

Comment: I'm not sure why you feel it's impossible to run phpmyadmin if you're installing separately when you can install phpmyadmin and adjust the EasyPHP configuration...  =/

Comment: @KevinRemisoski, at the time of writing this answer I am not using  `phpMyAdmin`. So I never researched about adjusting configuration. (now a days I am using both `phpMyAdmin` and `MySQL Workbench`) Any ways thank you for remembering me to update my answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever installed mysql before ?

You can check in services.msc. If so, open a terminal in administrator and run `sc delete mysql`. mysql, in the command, must be the name of the service.

Restart, reinstall EasyPHP and it might be solved.